# zxing - android - read multiples qr images

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

How i can do to read multiples QR images and get the code of all images at the same time?
For example: I have 3 QR images and when focus my camera to all images i want to read the 3 QR codes at the same time.

Comment: Is it any fix number of QR code which you want to read.?

Comment: Zxing can read only one QR Code at the same time. To achieve what you want you'd need to find a way to detect the coordinates in the image where every QR Code is shown. Then split the image in pieces where every piece contains one single QR Code. Finally use Zxing to decode every piece/code.

Comment: Is and not any fix number. I want to do for any way.

Comment: Jorge, espero que hables español jeje.
No se si viste la aplicacion "Google Googles" que escanea varios codigos.
En si necesito escanear varios codigos para un Google Glass, capaz que el Google Glass me permite hacer eso.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the `Zxing Barcode Scanner app`. It has option in *Settings to Scan Bulk Barcodes*. So you enable it and check it you can read Multiple QR codes at a time from one or more Images and also check the [Source code of Zxing library](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/)
 to Known the detailed Information .

Use the code in `core/`. You need [QRCodeMultiReader](http://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/multi/qrcode/QRCodeMultiReader.html)

Comment: QRCodeMultiReader is "multi" because it can read QR Code, 1D barcodes and other formats. It can't read more than one code at the same time.